# How to get first values of array?

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$predmeti = [
        'slo' => 'slovenščina',
        'mat' => 'matematika',
        'ang' => 'angleščina',
        'fot' => 'fotografija',
        'tir' => 'tipografija in reprodukcija',
        'tirv' => 'tipografija in reprodukcija vaje',
        'gob' => 'grafično oblikovanje',
        'mob' => 'medijsko oblikovanje',
];
```

Somewhere in code I want to get all first values of this array (slo, mat, ang...) How do I achive that?

I need to pass all the values in foreach statment after getting all first values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call the "first value" is the "key". You can use `array_keys` to get an array of all the keys from the first array:

```
$keys = array_keys($predmeti);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    // ... do something with the $key ...
}
```

But since you're using a foreach loop anyway, you can iterate the keys and values of the array together, and just ignore the `$value` variable:

```
foreach ($predmeti as $key => $value) {
    // ... do something with the $key ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "first values" you are talking about are the keys, the "second values" are the actual values. Try:

```
foreach ($predmeti as $key => $value) {
  print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
}
```

That should print

```
key: slo, value: slovenščina
key: mat, value: matematika
...
```